# tftpd-hpa inside VMware server fails to deliver files for PXEBoot

Tags: debian, vmware-esxi, pxe-boot, tftp

I've a PXE server for network installation. Everything was working fine until we virtualized the server using VMware ESXi 5.1.

When we try to boot a machine through the network, it got an IP from the DHCP server (running on the same machine) and it waits for TFTP until we get a timeout.

We are running Debian 7 Wheezy, with isc-dhcp-server and tftpd-hpa. Here are my conf files:

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
allow booting;
allow bootp;`

default-lease-time      1800;
max-lease-time          3600;

option space PXE;
option PXE.mtftp-ip code 1 = ip-address;
option PXE.mtftp-cport code 2 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-sport code 3 = unsigned integer 16;
option PXE.mtftp-tmout code 4 = unsigned integer 8;
option PXE.mtftp-delay code 5 = unsigned integer 8;
option PXE.discovery-control code 6 = unsigned integer 8;
option PXE.discovery-mcast-addr code 7 = ip-address;

class "PXE" {
    match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";
    next-server stormwind.if.ufrj.br;
    filename "pxelinux.0";
    option vendor-class-identifier "PXEClient";
    vendor-option-space PXE;
    option PXE.mtftp-ip 0.0.0.0;
}
```

/etc/default/tftpd-hpa

```
TFTP_USERNAME="tftp"
TFTP_DIRECTORY="/srv/tftp"
TFTP_ADDRESS="0.0.0.0:69"
TFTP_OPTIONS="--secure"
```

And I can confirm that tftpd is running and listening on the server:

```
netstat -a | grep tftp
udp        0      0 *:tftp                  *:*
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you download pxelinux.0 using a TFTP client?  What's that `next-server` setting pointing to?  What method did you use to virtualize the system?